# Electron JS Path Problems After Build and Move

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I build my project with Electron. Its run on Nodejs. I compile this project with Electron-Packager. It's run, but when i move compiled folder, project won't run I get some path errors.

```
export function getSafeWPPath(): string {
     let home = app.getPath('home');
     home = path.resolve(home, ".SafeWP");
     if (!fs.existsSync(home)) {
         fs.mkdirSync(home);
     }
     return home;
 }
```

I get

```
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
   at getSafeWPPath
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmrGk.png)

Answer (score 1):

its becuase it cannot find a path module. make sure you have added 'path' to dependencies instead of dev dependencies.